# Reading a file line by line with boost filesystem C++

Tags: file, parsing, boost, filesystems

I'm using the boost::filesystem library to open a file with a specific path file_path:

```
 fs::ifstream file(file_path);
    string str;
    vector<string> filenames;
    while(getline(file, str)){
        filenames.push_back(str);
    }
```

This code has been adapted from regular C++ code without boost. I initially was reading in a file placed in my current directory but I had to edit the path. Now it appears that getline is not working correctly. Is there a boost alternative to getline so that I can parse the file line by line and read them into the vector?

Thanks!

Comment: If your troubles started when you changed the file_path, perhaps opening the file does not succeed.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working correctly"?  You need to post the code, the expected behavior, and the actual behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer above is absolutely correct. In case anyone wants full code :

```
boost::filesystem::ifstream fileHandler(fileName);
string line;
while (getline(fileHandler, line)) {
    cout << line << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`boost::filesystem::ifstream` is just another input stream, and all standard algorithms apply to it the same way they apply to `std::ifstream`. `std::getline` works with it as well.